# Launch NestJs application with default admin user

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

If I'm creating a NestJs app with a TypeORM-managed database that considers 2 types of users (normal users and admin users) in which only admins can create other users (whatever type), what are the good practices to guarantee that, when the app starts, it has already a default admin there?

I've search online and found results about Seeding or Migrations, but it seemed to me that those are workarounds to use only in development.

How should this be handled if the app were to go to production?

Comment: You are talking about SQL users right ? Or some custom user ?

Comment: @JuanRambal, custom user. I have an entity called User.

Comment: Mmm in that case could give more context ? I dont understand what are you trying to do

Comment: It's just that: if only users can create other users, I need a user to exist from the beginning, otherwise it's kind of a deadlock.

Comment: Ok, in that case your solution is valid, using the OnModuleInit on your app module or database module ensures that your api have an admin user on start

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I figured a possible solution: implementing OnModuleInit on the UserService and have it query the DB for the default admin user and, if it doesn't exist, create it.

But still I don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: Worked well for me. I feel its a good solution. The lifecycle methods are very similar in Angular and meant for the same type of things.